# assign swf file in a player

Tags: vb.net, flash

im trying to do how to assign a specific file to play in a player. no need for file dialog.
what i need is if i click the button1 the flash will play.

i do like this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim swffile As String = "C:\Users\Rj Shadow\Documents\UM Buildings\BE.swf"

    AxShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(0, swffile)
    AxShockwaveFlash1.Play()
    AxShockwaveFlash1.Loop = False


End Sub
```

this does't work..

Answer (score 0):

Hit same problem. After a few hours - it's the order of the code that's important. In case anyone else stumbles here, this works:

```
    Dim flash1 As New AxShockwaveFlash
    .....
    flash1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(300, 23)
    Me.Controls.Add(flash1)
    flash1.Movie = "C:\Users\Steve\Scripts\Projects\CPWizBiz\Assets\Test SWFs\Artwork4.swf"
    flash1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(192, 400)
    flash1.Play()
```